# Creating directories under /mnt during %post portion of Kickstart

Tags: redhat, kickstart

In the %post section of my kickstart script, I've created multiple directories that's required before Puppet takes over. I noticed 2 of my directories under `/mnt` do not get created. I'm wondering if this has to do w/ the way kickstart handles temporary images and what not. I know I'm able to create directories since I created something under / (`mkdir -p /export/home`) during the process as well. Upon reboot I see `/export/home` but not `/mnt/volume1` and `/mnt/volume2`

Comment: Seems to be working now. no idea why it didnt work on two server builds.

Answer (score 3):

Try logging the %post section, as shown in [wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/KickStart , Logging %pre and %post](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/KickStart#line-50). All output and errors will be printed to a logfile.

I prefer the following method instead of `%post --log` because `--log` will sometimes miss some errors.

```
%post
exec < /dev/tty3 > /dev/tty3
chvt 3
echo
echo "################################"
echo "# Running Post Configuration   #"
echo "################################"
(

mkdir --verbose --parent /export/home
# Do more here

echo "#### Post-install DONE"

) 2>&1 | /usr/bin/tee /var/log/post_install.log
chvt 1
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure what happened, but I tried two additional mock installs and all is well now. But thank you for this tip!

Comment: If you use kickstart, then at some point you're going to run into a problem that can't be debugged without better logging. This is a sanity saver for me.

Comment: Hah, yea I've racked my brain over silly things before. Syntax errors and what not!